# Next-auth Sign in with bearer token skipping the form

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I need to sign in to a server using a bearer token only, is there a way to call the signin rest API just passing the token using the credentials provider?

in src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts i have:
`

```
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "myProviderID",
      name: "myProviderName",
      credentials: {},
      authorize: async credentials => {
        const user = await fetcher(userMe, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${cookies().get("token-bearer")?.value}`,
          },
          body: {
            csrfToken: await getCsrfToken(),
          },
        });

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
```

`

in mt page.tsx i have:

```
export async function getData() {

  const csrfToken = decodeURI(cookies().get("next-auth.csrf-token")?.value || "").split("|")[0];

  const myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.set("next-auth.csrf-token", csrfToken);
  myHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


  const res = await fetcher(`https://customUrlMappedInhostFile:3000/api/auth/signin/myProviderID`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log(res.url);
  }

  console.log("RES", res);

  return res;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const me = await getData();

  console.log("ME", me);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(me)}</div>;
}
```

but i get:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: fetch failed
```

One thing to consider is that im actuyally running the server in https and with a custom nam in the host file